# Read a word from a file

Tags: java, list, dictionary

If someone could help me figure out how to search if a word exists in a file, I would greatly appreciate it. I do know how to read an entire text file though.

And this is what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("words.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a word you would like to search for:");
    String word = sc.nextLine();

    List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        sc = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter( ",");

        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            final String wordFromFile = sc.nextLine();
            if (wordFromFile.contains(word)) {
                // a match!
                System.out.println("The entered word: " + word  + " exists in the dictionary");
                break;
            }

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(" cannot write to file " + file.toString());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Explain what exactly is not working. Don't make the people here to read the code, debug and find *what* doesn't work.

Comment: ***Once** the file is loaded, the user should be asked to search for a word* Load the `List` before asking the user for a word. Don't try and do both in one loop.

Comment: every word exists in the file, that's the output, even if i type asdkgh

Comment: We don't know if you file actually had asdkgh

Comment: we do, i make up those words just to get a " word not found" or something

Comment: How can it print "word not found" when you haven't made it to print. Edit your question and clarify what the exact problem is

Comment: Inset into the file or list you generate from the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate through all the words in file an insert each into a `HashSet` from the file first.  This is linear time `O(n)` to accomplish, no way around this as you got to read in the whole file.

Assuming one word from file it's like:

```
HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<>();
while (sc.hasNext()) {
    set.add(sc.nextLine();
}
```

If someone a sticker any they really want it read to a list type collection,  you can generate a HashSet like this from the list:

```
 Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(wordList);
```

*Note: This conversion operation is also `O(n)`, so to read it into a list and convert you're  `O(2n)`, which is still `O(n)`, but if this list is long far from optimal*

For the lookup and/or insertion of the new word you check, can then do it in `O(1)` time.

```
if (set.contains(word)) {
   //...blah..blah...bla...
} else {
   set.add(word);
}
```

Hence the *hash* in the name `HashSet`.

Comment: Your set example is missing the generic type on the left hand side!

Comment: @GhostCat not needed this case -- they're not pulling anything out of the set.  Can lose the right side generic too.  Generics just ensure type safety of the collection and allow you to avoid casting on retrieval from it.

Comment: Raw types are bad practice. If you are seriously not knowing that... You are basically completely turning a good answer into garbage with that single statement.

Comment: @GhostCat hmmm... a little extreme throwing the baby out with the bathwater reaction, but I see some merit in your point.  While supplying the generic type it does nothing for functional correctness of my answer and nothing in my code or the OP is would be in danger in this case from using raw types, it's better to have them there to prevent new coders from following the pattern and leaving them off where in normal practice.  Will add to my example on the right hand side of the assignment.

Comment: Hint: you want the generic type on the left side and empty "brackets" aka diamond operator on the right hand side. You removed on raw type and inserted another one instead. But still - have my vote back :-)

Comment: Whoops, yes, forget to leave the `<>`

Answer (score 0):

This might help you understand

```
public static void main(String a[]){
     File file = new File("words.txt");
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Enter a word you would like to search for:");
     String word = sc.nextLine();

     boolean exist = false;
     List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
     sc = new Scanner(file);

     while(sc.hasNext()){

           words.add(sc.next());

     }
     for(int i=0;i<words.size();i++){
           if(words.get(i).equals(word)){
                   System.out.println("The entered word: " + word  + " exists in the dictionary");
                   exist = true;
                   break;
           }
     }
     if(!exist){
            System.out.println("This word is not in the dictionary.");
            System.out.println("Do you want to add it");
            if(System.in.read() == 'y'){
                   words.add(word);
            }
     }
}
```

Comment: Please note that code only answers are discouraged. Take the time to explain things - instead of adding a sub standard answer to a sub standard question.

Comment: i will solve person's problem rather then spoon feeding. thanks @GhostCat

Comment: Then sorry you lack understanding of the policies of this community. You don't help people by dropping code. You help them understanding things. You teach fishing - instead of handing out fish.